# How to read in multiple arrays in one loop?

Tags: java, arrays, parallels

Here are my directions:

This program will use two arrays - these are called parallel arrays.  You will NOT be using an array of objects.
You will have a minimum of 6 methods in this application (including main())

inputData() - input from the data file into two arrays - the data file is below, call it "population.txt"
remember to check for the existence of the file before associating the Scanner object to it
displayCountries() - display all of the countries - just the countries

Can you please tell me why this will not run? I need to have the value of the population and the country name together so I can write it in a table later. So I am thinking that I need to read the first value into countryName and the first value into populationNum instead of reading them all in at the same time. The text that I am reading in is below the code. I do not know how to do that though. I am also wondering if I need the [25] when I instantiate. It gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
at Population.inputData(Population.java:32)
at Population.main(Population.java:13)
```

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Population{
   public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException{
      //Arrays
      String [] countryNames = new String [25];
      int [] populationNum = new int [25];
      //Input data from file into the array
      inputData(countryNames, populationNum);
      //Displays and calculations
      displayCountries(countryNames);
   } //end main()

   //this class gets the input for arrays from the file
   public static void inputData(String [] countryNames, int [] populationNum) throws IOException{
      File infile = new File("population.txt.");
      int index = 0;
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(infile); 
      while(scan.hasNext())
      for(int i = 0; i < countryNames.length; i++)
       countryNames[i] = scan.nextLine();
      for(int i = 0; i < populationNum.length; i++)
       populationNum[i] = scan.nextInt();
   } //end inputData()
   //this class displays the countries
   public static void displayCountries(String [] countryNames) {
      for(int i = 0; i < countryNames.length; i++)
         System.out.println(countryNames[i]);
   } //end displayCountries()
}//end class

Ghana
24333000
Brazil
193364000
Australia
23480970
Nigeria
170123000
Papua New Guinea
6888000
Mexico
108396211
Egypt
79221000
Iran
75078000
Myanmar
50496000
Belgium
10827519
Tuvalu
10000
russia
141927297
```

Comment: What is the actual format of the input?  Is each country on one line, and the population on the next line?  Or is some of this data on the same line?

Comment: Yes each input is on different lines, I have 24 lines with 12 numbers and 12 country names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read into both arrays in the same loop, like this:

```
int i = 0;
while(scan.hasNext()) {
    countryNames[i] = scan.nextLine();
    if (scan.hasNext()) populationNum[i] = scan.nextInt();
    if (scan.hasNext()) scan.nextLine(); // Go to the next line
    i++;
}
```

The two `for` loops inside the `while` are incorrect (not to mention that the second `for` loop is not even part of the `while`, because you omitted curly braces).

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/PXJll9)

Comment: Shouldn't the last one be `scan.nextLine()` instead of `scan.next()`?  I thought `scan.nextLine()` would just return whitespace up to and including the newline, but `scan.next()` will eat the next country name... I could be wrong, haven't tested it yet...

Comment: I did exactly this and get the same exception error

Comment: @AndrewMarbl did you try again after the edit?  I tried it and it should be correct, except that the output will have a lot of lines that say `"null"`--you'll need to figure out how to deal with those.

Comment: @AndrewMarbl Try putting an end-of-line mark on the last line.

Comment: Ok. It works. How would I get rid of the null's without hardcoding the number of array blocks?

Comment: @AndrewMarbl If you are allowed to use `ArrayList`s, use them instead of arrays. Otherwise, return `int` from `getInput` (the final value of `i` from the `while` loop).

Comment: Is there a way to email you one more question?

Comment: @AndrewMarbl If this is a new question, post it on the site. Usually, you get your answer faster. If it is a follow-up that needs context, link to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need { after while(scan.hasNext()) and closing } after two for loops. What is happening is while loop scans all data then the for loops try to do scan.next when the scanner is already at end of file. Hope this helps